# How do I know if my blas routines are highly optimized for my machine?

Tags: lapack, blas

I'm trying to install a modern version lapack (3.8.0) on my Centos 6.6 machine. The [directions](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn81/node20.html) say

> Ideally, a highly optimized version of the BLAS library already exists on your machine.

My version of blas was downloaded through `yum`:

```
$ yum info blas
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cogentco.com
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirror.web-ster.com
 * updates: mirrors.maine.edu
Installed Packages
Name        : blas
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.2.1
Release     : 5.el6
Size        : 710 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : The Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms library
URL         : http://www.netlib.org/lapack/
License     : BSD
Description : BLAS (Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms) is a standard library which
            : provides a number of basic algorithms for numerical algebra.
```

How do I know if this is 'highly' optimized for my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, really. They are not as optimized as they could be. I always build them for the specific machine, I need them on. The runtime differences are considerable. I just compared OpenBLAS as shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 and the one I built on my own.
The `dgemm` exhibits a runtime difference of in average 25%; `zgemm` is roughly 38% faster, with the self compiled libraries. This is harmless yet. `dgesvd` is even nearly twice as fast.